# How to add button image in normalstate,hoverstate,pressed state and disabled state in Renderer button using highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have used Renderer button in highcharts. I am having normal,hover and clicked images for a button . I want to use that images in the states of renderer button. How can I use that ? I have tried following code, but not working

```
var normalState = {};    
normalState.backgroundImage = "url(../assets/newBoxButton_normal.png)";

var hoverState = {};    
hoverState.backgroundImage = "url(../assets/newBoxButton_over.png)";

var pressedState = {};    
pressedState.backgroundImage = "url(../assets/newBoxButton_clicked.png)";

var disabledState = {};    
disabledState.backgroundImage = "url(../assets/newBoxButton_normal.png)";

var newBox = chart.renderer.button('Button',74,10,function(){
                                alert("Renderer button");   
                            },normalState,hoverState,pressedState,disabledState)
                             .add();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG elements do not have background-image attribute. You can put the image inside pattern tag and then reference it in fill attribute via `fill: url(#/pattern-id/)`.

Before you render the button, you need to pattern and images:

```
function addImagesAsPatterns(chart) {
  const renderer = chart.renderer
  const images = [
    ['normal', 'https://png.icons8.com/bar/ios7/25'],
    ['hover', 'https://png.icons8.com/bar-filled/ios7/25'],
    ['pressed', 'https://png.icons8.com/bar/office/16'],
    ['disabled', 'https://png.icons8.com/beer/ios7/25']
  ]

  function addPattern(imageUrl, id) {
    const pattern = chart.renderer.createElement('pattern').add(chart.renderer.defs).attr({
      width: 1,
      height: 1,
      id
    })

    renderer.image(imageUrl, 0, 0, 30, 30).add(pattern)
  }

  const ids = images.map(image => {
    const id = 'img-' + image[0]
    addPattern(image[1], id)

    return id
  })

  return ids
}
```

Render the button:

```
function renderButton () {
  const ids = addImagesAsPatterns(this)
  const url = id => `url(#${id})`

  this.cButton = this.renderer.button(null, this.plotLeft, this.plotTop, function () {
    this.setState(this.state === 2 ? 0 : 2)
  }, {fill: url(ids[0]), 'stroke-width': 2}, {fill: url(ids[1])}, {fill: url(ids[2])}, {fill: url(ids[3])}, 'rect').attr({ width: 15, height: 15}).add()
}
```

Call it on load:

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: renderButton
    }
  },
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/qjzr0sje/

Comment: Thanks lot. Really it helps me out.